# How to accumulate several data entry worksheets onto one 'Master' worksheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I accumulate stock records including **hyperlinks** entered on separate worksheets related to different areas in a work place onto one master worksheet where the total stock can be viewed, searched or sorted as required.  The formatting and columns are identical on all worksheets.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can reference other spreadsheets like so:
[Workbook_name]Sheet_name!Cell_address

So open your "master sheet" and find your desired cell, set the formula by typing equals and then use the formula above to reference your external worksheets.

For example:
[Sales.xlsx]Jan!B2:B5

If the work sheets are not in the same directory, you will need to include the full path in the first part of the formula like so:
[D:\info\Sales.xlsx]Jan!B2:B5

I hope this helps!